# Proving a set of vectors in linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_k \in R^n$ are linearly independent. Let $y \in R^n$ and assume that $y \not\in$ Span($v_1,\dots,v_k$). How can I show that ($v_1,\dots,v_k,y$) is linearly independent?

I know that for linearly independence the following equation has only the trivial solution:

$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_kv_k+a_{k+1}y=0$$

But how do I go about this proof?

Comment: Consider two cases: what happens if $a_{k+1}=0$ and what happens if $a_{k+1}\neq 0$. By the way: “proof-verification” is not an appropriate tag here, because you don’t have a proof you want us to check.

Answer (score 2):

If $a_{k+1}=0$, then the linear independence of $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ assures that all other $a_j$'s are equal to $0$. Otherwise,$$y=-\frac{a_1}{a_{k+1}}v_1-\cdots-\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}v_k.$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be proven by contradiction, assume that there exists a non-trivial solution for the equation (where ${{v_1, v_2... v_{k+1},y}}$ are linearly independent vectors)
$$
a_1 v_1+ a_2 v_2+a_3 v_3+...+a_k v_k+a_{k+1} y=0
$$

such that at least one of the coefficients is non-zero, (say $a_{k+1}$ is non-zero and rest all are $0$ ), then 
$$a_{k+1} y= 0$$
but $$ a_{k+1}\neq 0 \implies y=0 $$
which can not be the case, as all are linearly independent (non-zero) vectors.
Hence, $a_{k+1}$ must be equal to $0$, which shows that the above equation has only trivial solution.

Comment: For a proof by contradiction, you assume there is a non-trivial solution of that equation. Good. But after that, you only considered one special case of what the coefficients might be. That’s not a proof.